# How to add shipping method programmatically into carrier in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I want to add shipping methods programmatically into carrier table using my custom module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/carrier/#principles

You might want to look at an example:
https://github.com/prestarocket/myprestashop/blob/9000c9cc2837da1d31f9f69f077aa2c18b452daa/MyCarrierModule.php

https://github.com/FabienSerny/mymodcarrier/blob/d00771b1998bf7ec69196c3a4491e0022f7b6d08/mymodcarrier.php

Comment: I have added one module which generate new tab with my controller route link
after that I added new carrier using controller function

Now I want to update carrier programmatically, How can I update carrier?

Comment: All carriers are objects in the database. You need to get the instance of a carrier and update it. Take a look at how other free modules for shipping are working.